# Power transistor or relay?

Tags: transistors, relay

I'm going to use a microcontroller to switch a vehicle horn on and off intermittently for maybe one second on and one off for a period of 15 seconds; the horn will pull an estimated 3 Amps. I know I can do this with either a relay or transistor, but saving space/money is a concern and I'm really just not sure which way to go.

Comment: N-channel MOSFET (logic level).

Comment: Any reason as to why that's better?

Comment: I image the horn pulls 3A DC?  What voltage?  Will the micro share the same ground as the horn?

Comment: Will share same ground, at 12v DC.

Comment: What is more important: Space or money?  How many do you want to make?

Comment: Well it's a one off prototype situation currently, but space > cost.

Comment: Microcontroller can't drive typical relays directly, you will need small transistor to drive relay coil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either will work. A relay has the advantage that it can stand very high transient voltages and won't be disturbed by transients across the contacts.

A suitably rated MOSFET can work too, but you'll probably have to overrate it by quite a bit for it to be reliable. It may need a heat sink if you're operating in under-hood conditions at high ambient temperature (Rds(on) goes up quite a bit with temperature).

The relay is bigger (it will consume a bit more current, but that is immaterial in comparison to the 3A horn), and it will not need a heat sink.

Cost could definitely go either way, depending on quantity etc., so if it's a volume product I suggest pricing it out both ways before you decide.

If it's just a one-off, you can ignore cost and use a huge overkill MOSFET such as an [FDH5500](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/FD/FDH5500_F085.pdf) (I'm using this one for a vehicle application). **If** you feed it 10V at the gate (not directly from the micro, you'll need to step up the voltage), it has an Rds(on) not exceeding 0.01 ohm at 100°C. It won't need a heatsink for a 3A load and has a good chance of blowing a fuse without dying in case of a short. Even so, it's only about $4.50 in singles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BUZ11 N-MOSFET transistor.

It's a bit overkill (50V, 30A), but at Vgs = 5V you can draw 8A (see transfer characteristic in [datasheet](http://www.radiotechnika.hu/images/BUZ11.pdf)).

It has TO-220 package - smaller than typical relays capable to switch 3A current.

You probably won't need heatsink for it at 3A.

It's cheap (I found $3 per 5 pieces on ebay).

Alternatively - you can use 2SK2553 transistor. It's a bit smaller (LDPAK), its capable to transfer higher currents at Vgs = 5V but probably is more expensive.

You can also look at other N-channel mosfets with "logic-level" (you need Vgs < 5V to drive transistor gate directly from microcontroller).

Edit/added later:

All informations above apply to circuit with 5V (not 3.3V) microcontroller.
For 3.3V you need very low Vgs transistor.